# Joining wind speed and wind direction using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, climate

I have successfully exported wind speed to a csv file, and am trying to add wind direction. I know my wind direction calculation works and I can see it when printing `ERA5total`. If I understand correctly, I need to use an inner join, but I only end up with an empty csv file.

```
//  1. Setup
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0");
var NL = countries.filterMetadata('ADM0_NAME', 'equals', 'Netherlands');
var start_period = ee.Date('2018-07-01');
var end_period = ee.Date(new Date().getTime());

var ERA5 = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
     .filter(ee.Filter.date(start_period, end_period))
     .filterMetadata('hour', 'equals', 14);

var ERA5NL=ERA5.map(function(image){ 
   return image.clip(NL)});


//  2. Calculate wind speed as windspeed band
var ERA5windspeed = ERA5NL.map(function(image){
  var wind_10m = image.expression(
    'sqrt(u**2 + v**2)', {
      'u': image.select('u_component_of_wind_10m'),
      'v': image.select('v_component_of_wind_10m')
  }).rename('windspeed');
  var time = image.get('system:time_start');
  return wind_10m.set('system:time_start', time) } );
  

//  3. Calculate mean wind speed for entire NL per day
var ERA5meanspeed = ERA5windspeed.map(function(image){
  var meandict = image.select('windspeed').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: NL
  })
  return image.set(meandict); 
});


  //  4. Calculate wind direction as winddir band
var ERA5winddir = ERA5NL.map(function(image){
  var winddir = image.expression(
    'mod(180 + (180/3.14) * atan2(v,u),360)', {
      'u': image.select('u_component_of_wind_10m'),
      'v': image.select('v_component_of_wind_10m')
  }).rename('winddir');
  var time = image.get('system:time_start');
  return winddir.set('system:time_start', time) } );
  
  
//  5. Calculate mean wind direction for entire NL per day
var ERA5meandir = ERA5winddir.map(function(image){
  var meandict = image.select('winddir').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: NL
  })
  return image.set(meandict); 
});


//6. Join wind speed and wind direction datasets

// Use an equals filter to define how the collections match.
var filter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:index',
  rightField: 'system:index', 
});

 // Define the join.
var innerJoin = ee.Join.inner('primary', 'secondary');

// Apply the join.
var ERA5total = innerJoin.apply(ERA5meanspeed, ERA5meandir, filter);

// Display the result.
print('Join', ERA5total);


//7. Filter out wind speeds > 3 m/s and keep only yyyymmdd in output table
var ERA5x = ERA5total.filter(ee.Filter.lt('windspeed',3.0))  //select only wind speeds < 3 m/s
  .map(function(image){
      var yyyymmdd = ee.String(image.get('system:index')).slice(0,8) //slice date: only yyyymmdd left
    return image.set('date', yyyymmdd)
});

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ERA5x.sort('windspeed'),
  description: 'NL_mean_wind',
  selectors: ['date', 'windspeed', 'winddir']
});
```

Comment: I used part of your code to get wind direction but I think there's a mistake and `atan2(v,u)` should be `atan2(u,v)` given that [atan2 in GEE](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-atan2) works (x,y) and not (y,x). Could I be right? Thanks!

Comment: @pkry is correct that atan2 in GEE works using the "spreadsheet convention" but this specific calcuation done by Olivier uses u and v in the correct order. When you use the "pi/2 radians plus the arctan2()" approach as Olivier uses, then the order is arctan2(v, u) for the spreadsheet convention and arctan2(u, v) for the programming language convention. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60564849/9272260 for a Python implementation (using arctan2(u, v) which is the opposite order to the GEE example shown here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join is working fine, however the result isn't quite what you're expecting.

The matching images are set as properties on a new, otherwise empty, feature.
You can turn this into what you're expecting (a feature with simple properties) by mapping over the result and pulling the properties up from the images:

```
var ERA5total = innerJoin.apply(ERA5meanspeed, ERA5meandir, filter)
  .map(function(f) {
    var img1 = f.get('primary')
    var img2 = f.get('secondary')
    return ee.Feature(null).copyProperties(img1).copyProperties(img2)
  })
```